# How should I handle: Error C2039 'assign': is not a member of 'cl::string' in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, string, opencl

I want to build a simple OpenCL code in Visual Studio C++ but there is an error during the build. The error is

```
Error C2039 'assign': is not a member of 'cl::string'
```

The issue is about `cl::string`. However, when I build code with `std::string` instead of `cl::string`, it works very well.  How should I handle it?

Here is the code:

```
#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
#define __NO_STD_STRING
#include <iostream>


#ifdef MAC
#include<OpenCL.hpp>
#else
#include<CL/cl.hpp>
#endif // MAC



int main() {

    std::vector < cl::Platform > platforms;
    cl::string platformVendorName;

        cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
        std::cout << "There are " << platforms.size() << " platforms." << 
        std::endl << std::endl;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < platforms.size(); j++)
        {   
            platformVendorName = platforms[j].getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR>();

            std::cout << "CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR: " << 
            platformVendorName.c_str() << std::endl;

        }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to use std::string?

Class `string` defined in `cl` namespace is deprecated since at least OpenCL 1.2 and its use is not recommended. Taken from [cl.hpp](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/api/2.1/cl.hpp):

```
/*! \class string
 * \brief Simple string class, that provides a limited subset of std::string
 * functionality but avoids many of the issues that come with that class.

 *  \note Deprecated. Please use std::string as default or
 *  re-define the string class to match the std::string
 *  interface by defining STRING_CLASS
 */
class CL_EXT_PREFIX__VERSION_1_1_DEPRECATED string CL_EXT_SUFFIX__VERSION_1_1_DEPRECATED
```

Comment: @hossein1993 Then accept the answer if you are happy. Thanks.